# Angular router not loading the proper component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

I am beginner with angular and I have the followings routes.

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FrameComponent } from './ui/frame/frame.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './common/not-found/not-found.component';

const routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: 'src/app/login/login.module#LoginModule'
  },
  { 
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: FrameComponent,
    loadChildren: 'src/app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
  },

  {
      path: "**",
      component: NotFoundComponent,
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**dashboard.routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { OverviewComponent } from '../overview/overview.component';


const routes = [
  { 
    path: '',
    children:[
      {
        path: 'overview',
        component: OverviewComponent,
        //outlet: 'dashboard-inside'
      }
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

When navigating to `/dashboard` it loads the `FrameComponent` from the `AppRoutingModule`. 
But when navigating to `/dashboard/overview` it loads `NotFoundComponent` instead of `OverviewComponent` from second router.

I am still a beginner with Angular. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome. How exactly do you expect `/dashboard/overview` to navigate to `OverviewComponent` since that route (path) is not defined anywhere?

Comment: Isn't correctly defined in the children route of **dashboard.routing.module.ts**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't define your routes correctly

```
{ 
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: FrameComponent,
    loadChildren: 'src/app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
  }
```

This piece of code doesn't load lazily - you are not loading the childern over here you are just loading the component `FrameComponent` so angular does it for you

If your `FrameComponent` is part of `AppModule` you can just remove the `loadChildren` from the path and the angular will do the same routing for you

If it is not the part of `AppModule` then try something like this

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
 { 
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: 'src/app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
  }
```

Just load another module from the path and load the `component` you want from that module

**dashboard-routing.module.ts**

```
{ 
    path: '',
    component: FrameComponent,
    children:[
      {
        path: 'overview',
        component: OverviewComponent,
        //outlet: 'dashboard-inside'
      }
    ]
  }
```

Make sure you have declared the `FrameComponemt` inside the `DashboardModule` and that will make you to load the route you want

Now if the path is `/dashboard` angular will load the dashboard module and check for the path `''` next to the `/dashboard` so it will load the `FrameComponent` then when you try to access path `/dashboard/overview` routing will load the child route and `OverviewComponet` will be loaded

Hope everything will work good - please feel free to reach me if you have any doubts - Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `component: FrameComponent` from the dashboard route and move it into the dashboard routing module.

```
  { 
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: 'src/app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
  },


  { 
    path: '',
    component: FrameComponent,
    children:[
      {
        path: 'overview',
        component: OverviewComponent,
      }
    ]
  },
```

And I guess you should import your modules in core one.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition in `dashboard.routing.module.ts` is wrong.

Try this instead:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { OverviewComponent } from '../overview/overview.component';


const routes = [
  { 
    path: 'overview', // <-- should be in root.
    component: OverviewComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```